# android ndk mupdf build error

Tags: android, build, java-native-interface, mupdf

I am trying to make a project to read pdf in android phone.

So, I created the normal Android Project and installed the android-ndk-r6-windows.

And I built the 'libmibookreader.so' and set the native functions in my java class.

But after compiling my project I have a serious Error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library mibookreader not found
```

Why this error caused?

I really don't know. I referenced the address of "http://flytgr.thoth.kr/blog/697421".

I followed down as the reference document described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `library` was not loaded by the kernel. Are you sure that you placed your library inside the `libs/armeabi/` folder of your project?

Check the logcat when you deploy your application, you should see some messages there that your library was loaded.

If you don't you could also try to use `System.loadLibrary(libPath);` to manually load your library.